# Fast reading of data from text file

Tags: python-3.x, bash, numpy, matplotlib

I have a bash script which calls python scripts.
My python scripts reads data from text file (mostly np.loadtxt(filename))
The text file has numerical data 12,000 rows and 48 cols floats.

Reading these files again and again while plotting them is time consuming. just for small change in down-stream processing i have to read these file again and again. even for small changes in title i need to read these file.

is there a way i can minimize this data reading. Can i make these file reading process faster.

Below is my code

```
#!/bin/bash

################# This script should be run after production run of remd
export root=`pwd`
printf "Root dir $root\n"
psf=(pwat_heq.psf pu8_heq.psf u8t4_heq.psf)
pdb=(pwat_heq.pdb pu8_heq.pdb u8t4_heq.pdb)
ori=(pwat_ori.pdb pu8_ori.pdb u8t4_ori.pdb)
extract=(extract.psf extract.pdb) 
solu=("1leo_5fpps_pwat" "1leo_5fpps_u8" "1leo_5fpps_u8_t4")

###############################################################################
#                    change according to you simulation system                #
###############################################################################
select_system(){
    cd $root
    eqheatpdb=${pdb[$l]}        # VERY IMPORTANT
    eqheatpsf=${psf[$l]}
    oristr=${ori[$l]}
    extractpsf=${extract[0]}
    extractpdb=${extract[1]}
    # pddcd=${dcd[$l]}
    jobnum=2                  # VERY IMPORTANT CHANGE JOB-NUMBER
    cd ${solu[$l]}
    printf "\ncurrent working dir ${root}\n"
    printf "\ncurrent working system ${eqheatpdb} and ${eqheatpsf}\n\n"
}
dir_structure(){
    mkdir -p recen/{0..47}
    mkdir -p final_nativecontacts/{0..47}
    mkdir extract
    mkdir rmsd
    cp $root/${solu[2]}/anal/*.{py,inp,str} . 
}
call_python(){
    printf "contour python script running"
    python contour.py
}
```

Contour.py example

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d

txt="I need the caption to be present a little below X-axis"
paths=["1leo_5fpps_pwat", "1leo_5fpps_u8", "1leo_5fpps_u8_t4"]
temp = np.linspace(298,500,48).reshape(48,1)

f, ax = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True)
for i in range(3):
    filename1=open("{}/{}/anal/all_frac.dat".format(os.environ["root"], paths[i]))
    xf = np.loadtxt(filename1, dtype=float)
```

Comment: I guess your best bet would be to move more of the functionality to the python side. Within the python script you can of course keep the data open as long as you want...

Comment: I don't see where you call `python contour.py`. The call is in the unused (!) function `call_python`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save Numpy array in a binary file after you read it first time, reading from binary will be much faster. To modify Contour.py:

```
for i in range(3):
    filename1=open("{}/{}/anal/all_frac.dat".format(os.environ["root"], paths[i]))
    filename1_npy_cache = filename1 + ".npy"
    if Path(filename1_npy_cache).is_file():
        xf = np.load(filename1_npy_cache)
    else:
        xf = np.loadtxt(filename1, dtype=float)
        np.save(filename1_npy_cache, xf)  # delete the file if content changes
```

See more here:

- https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.save.html
- https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.load.html

Comment: can i also use os.path.isfile(filename1). is there any advantage of using Pathlib because i will have to import it.

Comment: Pathlib is native for Python ≥ 3.6, but for this simple purpose os.path.isfile is definitely fine too.